# Do birth defects in the neck limit the range of some singers?

Tags: voice, voice-training

Some people have a birth defect in their neck, so they can’t bend their head up or down as much as other singers can.

Can such singers learn to sing higher pitched notes and lower pitched notes with practice,  or does this birth defect limit their ability to reach very high or very low notes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't get high notes by bending your head up, or low notes by bending it down!  So, in itself, there's no reason why limited mobility such as you describe should affect singing.